# Excel VBA's SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

In my excel VBA function, 'strSQL' helps me to get perfect result in case text length of all records in all Data Fields (below) 255 char otherwise the function return empty value for all records if any cell in that particular field holds more than 255 characters.

```
strSQL = "SELECT [Company Name], [ProfileType], [DataField0],[DataField1],
           [DataField2],[DataField3],[DataField4],[DataField5],[DataField6],[DataField7] 
           FROM [Data$] WHERE [Company Name] = 'XYZ' ORDER BY [Heading_Order];"
```

I am using ADODB for establish the connectivity.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: There is no question, and absence of context makes this hard to reply

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The question is, why the Recordset is returning empty field values for all records if a single cell in the source location has a text value with length greater than 255 char and how can I resolve the problem?

Comment: Are you retrieving the records from an MS Access database? (If so, please correct the tag - [access] is nothing to do with MS Access - use the [ms-access] tag.)  Or are you retrieving the data from another Excel spreadsheet?  (Which is what I usually think of when I see a table name ending with a `$`.)

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing with the results of your query?

If you are trying to insert them into an Access table, check the data type of that table to ensure it is not a `Text` field. This has a limit of 255 characters. 
For larger text fields use `Memo` (or `Long Text`)

Other than this your data may be truncated to 255 characters if the first 8 records contain 255 or fewer characters. The Microsoft Excel ODBC driver will, by default, scan the first 8 rows of your data to determine the type of data in each column. Try converting the data type of the column to text (or even move the row with more than 255 characters to the first row)

Comment: The data is stored in Excel and I am fetching records to send each cells value in some predefined PowerPoint shapes.

Comment: It may be due to the data type of the column in Excel, I have updated my answer. I agree with other comments that it may be worth wording your question more clearly

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great way to convert a SQL string to VBA code.

Creating the form

The form just needs two text boxes, and a command button. SQL statements can be quite long, so you put the text boxes on different pages of a tab control.

```
    Create a new form (in design view.)
    Add a tab control.
    In the first page of the tab control, add a unbound text box.
    Set its Name property to txtSql.
    Increase its Height and Width so you can see many long lines at once.
    In the second page of the tab control, add another unbound text box.
    Name it txtVBA, and increase its height and width.
    Above the tab control, add a command button.
    Name it cmdSql2Vba.
    Set its On Click property to [Event Procedure].
    Click the Build button (...) beside this property.
    When Access opens the code window, set up the code like this:

Private Sub cmdSql2Vba_Click()
    Dim strSql As String
    'Purpose:   Convert a SQL statement into a string to paste into VBA code.
    Const strcLineEnd = " "" & vbCrLf & _" & vbCrLf & """"

    If IsNull(Me.txtSQL) Then
        Beep
    Else
        strSql = Me.txtSQL
        strSql = Replace(strSql, """", """""")  'Double up any quotes.
        strSql = Replace(strSql, vbCrLf, strcLineEnd)
        strSql = "strSql = """ & strSql & """"
        Me.txtVBA = strSql
        Me.txtVBA.SetFocus
        RunCommand acCmdCopy
    End If
End Sub


http://allenbrowne.com/ser-71.html
```